# Is this implementation of memoized computation correct?

Tags: java, concurrency

I needed to implement a simple generic wrapper for computation memoization, with ability to reset the memoized value on demand. Computation is potentially long-running, and so reset shouldn't block for too long - ideally, it just marks the current state as "dirty" and returns.

Here's what I did:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class CachedValue<A> {
    private Callable<A> creator;
    private Lock computationLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Lock resultLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private volatile A cached = null;
    private volatile boolean wasCleared = false;

    public CachedValue(Callable<A> creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public A get() {
        if (cached != null) {
            return cached;
        } else {
            computationLock.lock();
            try {
                if (cached != null) {
                    return cached;
                } else {
                    while (true) {
                        wasCleared = false;
                        A computed = creator.call();
                        resultLock.lock();
                        try {
                            if (!wasCleared) {
                                cached = computed;
                                return cached;
                            }
                        } finally {
                            resultLock.unlock();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                computationLock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        resultLock.lock();
        try {
            cached = null;
            wasCleared = true;
        } finally {
            resultLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work, but I'm no expect in parallel programming, so I maybe I missed some deadlock or efficiency issues?

Comment: who is setting `wasCleared` to true?

Comment: @SMA - reset() does. So that if some thread was already in process of computing a value when `reset` was called, the result that will be computed later won't be used, and recomputation will happen again.

Comment: So you need to protect wasCleared as it forms a critical section for you and two threads can independently access it like one thread working on reset and another on get method.

Comment: @SMA - you mean I could get NPE if one thread got to "cached = computed;", while the other proceeded to "cached = null;"?

Comment: Yes very much... You need to protect both wasCleared and cached variable atomically.

Comment: @SMA - so I will need another lock for them, in addition to the one that protects the computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to protect `cached` and `wasCleared` variable as these can be reset using `reset` method from one thread while `get` method being called from another thread which would work on same set of variables.

You could use the same reentrant lock in reset method as:

```
public void reset() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        cached = null;
        wasCleared = true;
    } finally {
         lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted reset to be very quick - if I use the same lock, reset will block for the whole computation time.

Comment: It has to be and that's the way it has to be and that's how you ensure atomicity and visibility and avoid race condition as being discussed in comment above.

Comment: That's not good - reset() may be called as a result of some user action (from gui), and get() is called by background thread - thus gui thread will be blocked for a long time.

Comment: Not sure why you are calling callable instead of delegating it to a thread in background then?

Comment: The idea is to use this a drop-in wrapper for some method on an object - for example, there's a huge graph, and we want to cache result of some long-running algorithm on it (TSP, for example). While TSP happily churns away, user may edit the graph, and we will invalidate the computation. And since the caller of this wrapper treats it as a simple method, creating background thread seems excessive - we would need to wait for it's completion anyway. I updated the code with possible two-lock solution to the race condition you pointed out.

Comment: No that wont work. Consider again one thread calling get and another reset. You are again in the same position. Your operation needs to be atomic and you need to have to use just one lock.

Comment: Let's say thread A called get and is recomputing the value, and thread B called reset. If B grabs the resultLock before A finished the computation, then wasCleared gets set to true, and A has to recompute the value. If thread A gets to the resultLock first, then it finishes the computation and returns the result, and B clears the cached value afterwards. I'm probably missing something - what is the problem here?